# Как разделить элементы массива на элементы другого массива? Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Мне надо разделить элементы двумерного массива разделить на элементы одномерного массива. т. е.:

```
a = np.array([
      [1, 2, 3],
      [6, 9, 8],
      [14, 3, 4],
      [0, 1, 9]
])

b = np.array([
      [1, 2, 3, 4]
])
```

надо разделить элементы каждого `i`-того подмассива `a`, на каждый `i`-й элемент массива `b` т. е.

```
a[0] = a[0] / b[0]
a[1] = a[1] / b[1]
a[2] = a[2] / b[2]
a[3] = a[3] / b[3]
```

но без перебора, без циклов, чтобы красиво и по `numpy`-евски

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правда непонятно зачем `b` сделан двойной вложенности (если будет одинарной, то убрать `[0]`). Но всё равно как-то так:

```
c = a / b[0][:,None]
```

Результат.

```
array([[1.        , 2.        , 3.        ],
       [3.        , 4.5       , 4.        ],
       [4.66666667, 1.        , 1.33333333],
       [0.        , 0.25      , 2.25      ]])
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: кстати, ```b``` получилось двойной вложенности по моей оплошности

Comment: @zolars Если ответ вам помог, то не забудьте пометить его как правильный. Если вы не знаете, как это сделать, просмотрите [инструкцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется здесь лучше (понятнее) воспользоваться методом [.reshape()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
res = a / b[0].reshape(-1, 1)
```

результат:

```
In [206]: res
Out[206]:
array([[1.        , 2.        , 3.        ],
       [3.        , 4.5       , 4.        ],
       [4.66666667, 1.        , 1.33333333],
       [0.        , 0.25      , 2.25      ]])
```

Смысл `matrix.reshape(-1, 1)` - изменяем размерность матрицы таким образов, чтобы получилась матрица с **одним столбцом** (второй параметр - `1`), а число строк (первый параметр - `-1`) Numpy вычислит сам. При задании параметра `-1` число элементов по указанной оси будет подсчитан автоматически. В данном случае число строк будет равно числу элементов в матрице `matrix`.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! и за то что указали направление что мне надо изучать )

Answer (score 1):

Просто нужно привести массивы к правильной форме для деления, для этого нужно транспонировать (повернуть) массив `b` и этого достаточно:

```
print(a/b.T)
```

Вывод:

```
[[1.         2.         3.        ]
 [3.         4.5        4.        ]
 [4.66666667 1.         1.33333333]
 [0.         0.25       2.25      ]]
```

Хотя уметь работать со срезами и изменять форму массивов, конечно полезно, но в данном случае достаточно знать про транспонирование `.T`

Comment: спасибо за ответ! и за то что указали направление что мне надо изучать )

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array([
      [1, 2, 3],
      [6, 9, 8],
      [14, 3, 4],
      [0, 1, 9]
])

b = np.array([
      [1, 2, 3, 4]
])
res = a / b # ERROR
res = a / b.reshape(-1, 1) # OK
[[1. 2. 3.]
 [3. 4.54.]
 [4.66666667 1. 1.33333333]
 [0. 0.25 2.25 ]]
```

a/b так невыдет потому что в массиве a 4 строки а в массиве b 1 строка
надо транспонировать массив b

x = b.reshape(-1, 1)